# Azure Devops does not have authorization to perform action Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to automate the setup of the service principal required for letsEncrypt, executed from Azure DevOps. I am running the following code

```
Write-Host ("Getting roles for " + $letsEncryptApplication.ApplicationId)
$letsEncryptContributorRole = Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Contributor -ServicePrincipalName $letsEncryptApplication.ApplicationId
if ($letsEncryptContributorRole -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "Creating contributor role for lets encrypt service principal"
    $letsEncryptContributorRole = New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Contributor -ServicePrincipalName $letsEncryptApplication.ApplicationId
} else {
    Write-Host "Contributor role for lets encrypt service principal already exists"
}
```

to which I get the following error on the line New-AzureRmRoleAssignment

```
does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/15ed030e-195f-4fc0-bbb9-cfcf581a1c00'.
```

I have been through app registrations for the Azure DevOps service principal exceuting this code and given it everything I think is relevant in active directory:

- Read and write all applications
- Manage apps that this app creates or owns
- Read and write directory data
- Read all users' basic profiles
- Read all users' full profiles

What permission do I need to give my Azure DevOps service principal so I can automate this part of the deployment?

Comment: same deal. grab the object id and assign it permissions on azure subscription level, not on azure ad level

Comment: I've made it a contributor. I still get the same error

Comment: contributors cant modify permissions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor

Comment: Then how can I make it so they do?

Comment: Ok, so I have to make it Owner. That seems to be the only way. Why you've marked my question as a duplicate when it clearly is not I do not know.

Comment: it is a dupe. the error text is the same, the solution is the same. why isnt it a duplicate?

Comment: The solution is not the same. The solution is to make it an owner. Your other question is not relevant

Comment: if you know this better than I do, why do you ask this question? if you apply solution from that question to your problem you solve your question. doesnt that define duplicate? also, consider upvoting that answer, since I've effectively answered your question twice

Comment: As you've marked this question as a duplicate I can no longer post the propert answer to it. Just argue with someone about who knows best. Thanks for that

Comment: btw, in fact, you dont have to be an owner, custom role will do. but you surely know that

Comment: Oh good answer, but different to the other one... If only you would put that as the answer I could mark is as correct. Shame you have marked this as a duplicate...

Comment: thats what you get for helping people. i hope you feel good about yourself

Comment: I have upvoted your comments which are useful. Ditto

Comment: @4c74356b41 please unmark this question as duplicate. I have found this question and it was useful to me, while the supposed "duplicate" was not.

Comment: In my opinion this question should be reopened. The "duplicate", which is related but not the same, does not tell what role or permission is needed to fix the problem stated in the question.
A proper answer should explain that either the user needs to have the Owner role or a custom role with the action "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write" must be created. 
This should be written in a proper answer to this question.
In my opinion a good answer would also show how to create a custom role with the required Action

Comment: Please can people vote using the link under the question to reopen the question so it can be properly answered?